# Moving from Firebase's Angular API to Android API

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase

I had made an application in Angular using Firebase API.
The concept was that a user logs in to create a dish (in dishes tree structure in forge) and the dish's referenceId is saved in the user's json tree(which is at the same hierarchy as is 'dishes') in forge.

In Angular, I created a scope Array and then filled that array using getUserDishes() method bellow.
Thus, in the HTML displaying the dish only that particular user created.

Details are as follows:

**Forge:**

```
"dishes" : {
    "-JVrqxyCG16PAJ0te8VM" : {
      "category" : "-JWLmke98kFmc20h8qsF",
      "description" : "Meat balls lamb, with onion,roasted garlic,olive oil,herbs,spice sauce brava.",
      "name" : "Balls Lamb with Brava Sauce",
      "owner" : "User A",
      "photo" : "Image_URL_1",
      "price" : 395
    },
    "-JVrrFShm8cR_YbzGEWo" : {
      "category" : "-JWLmBkPBMJUUiAmcuKa",
      "description" : "Typical tapa in Spain with fried eggs,ptoatoes,chorizo,ham,garlic bread.",
      "name" : "Eggs Sevillana",
      "owner" : "User A",
      "photo" : "Image_URL_2",
      "price" : 325
    },
    "-JVvY3yQcKia6J9-85ku" : {
      "description" : "Example Description",
      "name" : "Example Dish",
      "owner" : "User B",
      "photo" : "Image_URL_3",
      "price" : 100
    }
},

"users" : {
        "User A" : {
          ".priority" : "simplelogin:72",
          "dishes" : {
            "-JVrqxyCG16PAJ0te8VM" : "-JVrqxyCG16PAJ0te8VM",
            "-JVrrFShm8cR_YbzGEWo" : "-JVrrFShm8cR_YbzGEWo"
          }
        "User B" : {
          ".priority" : "simplelogin:73",
          "dishes" : {
            "-JVvY3yQcKia6J9-85ku" : "-JVvY3yQcKia6J9-85ku"
        }
    }
```

**Controler Logic:**

```
  var dishesref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'dishes');
  var usersref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
    .
    .
    .
    getUserDishes: function () {
      var dishes = {};
      if (User.signedIn()) {
        var user = User.getCurrent();        
        var userObj = $firebase(usersref.child(user.username)).$asObject();

        userObj.$loaded( function () {
            angular.forEach(userObj.dishes, function(dishId) {
              dishes[dishId] = $firebase(dishesref.child(dishId)).$asObject();
            });
        });
      }
      return dishes;
    },
```

**Angular Code**

```
<div ng-repeat="(categoryId, category) in categories">
<h1>{{category.name}}</h1>
<li ng-animate="'animate'" class="artist cf" ng-repeat="(dishId, dish) in dishes | filter: query | orderBy: artistOrder:direction">
  <!-- <div ng-repeat="(categoryId, category) in categories"> -->
    <div ng-if="dish.category === categoryId">
      <a href="" ng-href="#/details/{{dishId}}">
      <img ng-src="{{dish.photo}}" alt="Photo of {{dish.name}}">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>{{dish.name}}</h2>
        <h2>{{dish.Id}}</h2>
        <h3>{{dish.price}} INR</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
</li>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to replicate the same concept in Firebase's Android API.
I have successfully modified the [android chat example](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) to display all the dishes (i.e. all the items in 'dishes' are visible from the forge).
Some changes are desired in this approach.

> I need to display only dishes which have come from User A.
>   For that I need to replicate the above concept in Android which is already implemented in angular.

You can find the Android Project Repository: [Click Here](https://github.com/divenom/android-chat-modified)

**Any hint on how to achieve this in Android?** Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, share the relevant code please. Or preferably: create a minimal code example that reproduces the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes I did try modifying the android-chat example provided by Firebase. I have commited my repo on github. This is the working example. Please have a look. 
https://github.com/divenom/android-chat-modified

Comment: If you are having trouble with an Android project, provide a minimal reproduction of your problem. Don't ask for us to go to an external place to look at the entire application, most of which probably works fine and has nothing to do with your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok for your better understanding I will rephrase the question for you again, I might have written too much info in the question. Please give me some time. Thanks. Also, There is no error in the android code. I just wanted to know the approach which would help me to replicated the functionality in android. Again, plz gimee some time. I'll get back to u with proper rephrased question!